# How can i open the last file I created in php using a button

Tags: php, file, submit, fopen

I was able to create a file using the data the user inputs in the form. The first input field takes what the user inputs and makes that the title of the file. The contents or message is taken from the textarea tag and adds it to this file and when i click submit the file is created. The problem is i have another button that when i click should be able to display the contents of the file i created the previous step. I am using another submit button to try and display the contents of teh file to the webpage.

this is code used to create the file.

```
if(isset($sub) && $fname && $txt){
    
    $myFile = fopen("$fname.txt", 'wb');
    fwrite($myFile, $txt);  
    fclose($myFile);
```

Comment: Why not using MYSQL database to store the info?

Answer (score 0):

Just save the path of the file, you can use `$_SESSION` if you want to save it across all the session.

```
session_start();

$path = "$fname.txt";
if(!$myFile = fopen($path, 'wb')) // Checks if the file can be opened
{
  exit;
}
if (!fwrite($myFile, $txt)) // Checks if the write was successful
{ 
  exit;
}
$_SESSION["recentFile"] = $path;
fclose($myFile);
```

Now you can access the last path using

```
session_start();

echo file_get_contents($_SESSION["recentFile"]);
```